# Update HTML with @Html.Partial MVC 5

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I am new to MVC so please bear with me.

I have a view called "Edit.cshtml" which basically gets the information stored in my model so the user can update their details. The view code is

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
            <fieldset>
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
                @Html.Partial("RsvpForm", Model)
            </fieldset>
        }
```

This works, however, I would like to change a label name of a button or any other control from the HTML rendered object that comes back from the `@HTML.Partial` call.

The button text that I want to change which is rendered above is

```
   <div class="text-center">
        <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Submit RSVP" /> // Change the value basically to "Update RSVP"
    </div>
```

Is this possible? And if so, how?

** Edit ""

Javascript is another option,

Comment: Not clear what your asking. Is the button in `Edit.cshtml` or the partial. How is the value determined

Comment: Hi Stephen, apologies, I have started working with MVC this morning so thought it would be unclear! the button is declared in another view called RSVP.CSHTML, I am using the same layout to add and npow edit the information, hence why I have .partial (again is this right?) but the value (text) of the button is hardcoded in the RSVP view

Comment: Not sure why you need a partial - do you currently have `Create` and `Edit` methods? And what do you want the button text to be based on what condition

Comment: Well I have 2 ActionResults methods in the controller so I am returning two views, for the creation, just default `return View();` and for editing I return the object that matches what they type `return View(guestRepository.Find(id));` (This is Entity Framework, so dont worry about it)

Comment: You don't really need a partial. You can have 2 get methods `Create()` which returns View("Edit", new YourModel()) and `Edit(int id)` and a single post method `Edit(YourModel model)` and then in the view `@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit"))`.

Comment: Brilliant, much simpler, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take a `Viewbag` and set its value like `Viewbag.data = "Update RSVP";` and set button value with `Viewbag` as shown :

```
<div class="text-center">
    <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="@Viewbag.data" /> 
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought Viewbags were frowned upon!